# Logitech Mouse: One Click = 2 Keys Pressed

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Is it possible to program logitech mouse with lua script to press 2 keys (J and K) when I press a mouse button?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
function OnEvent(event, arg, family)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then  -- mouse button 5
      PressAndReleaseKey("J", "K")
   end
end
```